# displaying a line of text - exception handling

Tags: python, file, text, line, except

I want to enter such a code so that it displays the content of the line indicated by the user (in the form of a number read from the keyboard). Handle the exception when the list range (number of lines) is exceeded.
Here is the code:

```
import linecache
try:
    number = int(input("Line: "))
    lines = linecache.getline("text.txt", number)
    print(lines)
except:
    print("no such line was found")
```

the program correctly reads the contents of the line, but when I want to handle the exception, select a line outside the text.txt range, e.g. line 250 which does not exist, it does not display the exception "no such line was found", how can i improve it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
linecache.getline("test.txt", number)
```

Doesn't generate excepetion in case the row number doesn't exist, just return `''`.

So you can do something like this:

```
import linecache
number = int(input("Line: "))
lines = linecache.getline("text.txt", number)
print(lines)
if lines == '':
    print("no such line was found")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so it can't be done with a try / except block?

Comment: Using line cache.getline not that I know